# Small Help with Table Script?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i am new to SQL and i have a small question. i am writing a table script and i have question about two fields in that table. Here is the Table structure :

```
Billing

CustomerName
CustomerPhone
BGFlag (Y/N)
UpdateIndicator (B=Before,A=After)
```

My question is, do i have to write script for **(Y/N)** in BGFlag and  **(B=Before,A=After)**
 in UpdateIndicator in the create table script. what i am thinking is i just have to create table with these column names and (Y/N), (B=Before,A=After) is the data for that two columns which i will get in sample file. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like that is just application-specific metadata about those columns. You could put that in extended properties of the table, but nobody except a curious DBA is going to see it.

Keep in mind, even if the data you are *importing* into your database uses Y/N and B/A, you can always transform that into a bit value (0/1), which seems a better idea from a field design perspective.

Or, if you literally want it to hold those text values (Y/N and B/A), then just use a CHAR(1) field. The risk, though, is that anyone could put any single-character text value in these columns.

Comment: Hi Brad, so how would Y/N or B/A data would come in that two columns? will there be any store proc for that?

Comment: Totally depends on how you are importing it. If this was a regular, ongoing import, you would create an SSIS package, which allows you to set up "mappings" to make sure that the Y/N and B/A values are properly converted to 1/0 for a bit column. For a simpler approach, go with the CHAR(1), and just import it as normal text.